# metafont hash symbol

Tags: metafont

What does the # symbol mean when it follows a variable name.  e.g.

`arrow_len#` vs `arrow_len`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Metafont works in a grid determined by the current resolution and only with numbers, not dimensions. In a parameter file you specify dimensions such as `pt#`, for example

```
ht#:=6pt#;
```

and then you can work in the pictures with `ht`, after having said

```
define_pixels(ht);
```

For example,

```
ht#:=6pt#; define_pixels(ht);show ht;
```

will print `216` when the value of `hppp` is 36 (that corresponds to a resolution of 2602 dots per inch, the default when a mode has not been specified). In this way, `ht` will always represent the number of pixels necessary to cover a distance of 6pt. In the drawing of a character it would be safe to say

```
ht:=6pt;
```

since the resolution is already known. In a parameter file such as `cmr10.mf` it's necessary to specify parameters as "sharp dimensions", so they will be resolution independent, since it's not known a priori when the resolution will be set (before or after setting the font parameters). For example, `logo10.mf` says

```
% 10-point METAFONT logo
font_size 10pt#;  % the "design size" of this font
ht#:=6pt#;    % height of characters
xgap#:=0.6pt#;    % horizontal adjustment
u#:=4/9pt#;    % unit width
s#:=0;      % extra space at the left and the right
o#:=1/9pt#;    % overshoot
px#:=2/3pt#;    % horizontal thickness of pen
input logo    % now generate the font
bye      % and stop.
```

and `logo.mf` starts with `mode_setup` which sets, among other things, the resolution.

Similarly, dimensions that must be "output" should be specified in "sharp form"; from `digits.mf` we get

```
beginchar("1",9u#,fig_height#,0);
```

because this will write the correct value in points in the `gf` file; but in the definition of the character's shape `u` is used. It's a bit complicated; one should keep in mind that

```
a#=1pt#;define_pixels(a);
```

will assign the value `1` to `a#` and the value of `hppp` to `a` and you always know when you need the measure in points or the actual number of pixels.

Notice also that changing the value of `a` will *not* change the value of `a#`, it's the other way around with the help of the `define_pixels` function.